# Access Directly Action After Set As Default Page / Home Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

In my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Results", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It's could be accessed by `localhost/`

How to make it also accessed by its actual link `localhost/Search/Results`.

After I make it default, the actual direct link displaying `Resource cannot be found`

[image]

Comment: any other routing present in route.config ?

Comment: @MangeshAuti nope

Comment: In my case, all are working  `http://localhost:5555`  `http://localhost:5555/Search` `http://localhost:5555/Search/Results` `http://localhost:5555/Search/Results/1`

Comment: @MangeshAuti I use MVC 4. What is it affected by MVC version?

Comment: You are upgraded your project from anyversion to current? Check your dll or web. Config file might be something duplicate or corrupt

Answer (score 0):

RouteConfig.cs:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", id =     UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

Controller:

```
          public class SearchController : Controller
           {
           public ActionResult Index()
            {
              return View("Results");
            }
         }
```

Now,it will work.

```
                      OR
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Results", id =     UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Controller:

```
          public class SearchController : Controller
           {
           public ActionResult Results()
            {
              return View("");
            }
         }
```